# Testing actor system

Tags: akka

i have a next code

```
class MySystem(outerResourse: OuterResourse) extends Actor {

  val firstActor = context.actorOf(Props(new FirstActor(outerResourse)), "first")

  val secondActor = context.actorOf(Props(new SecondActor(firstActor)), "second")

  secondActor ! Go

  def receive = {
    case x: AnotherMessage => printl(s"another message: $x")
    case x => println(x)  
  }
}


class FirstActor(outerResourse: OuterResourse) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
   case Test => 
     context.parent ! AnotherMessage 
     sender ! "ok"
  }
}

class SecondActor(firstActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Go => firstActor ! Test
    case "ok" => println("ok")
  }
}
```

Here `OuterResourse` is a any resourse - file, internet connection...

i would like to check a behavior, but i in embarrassment, i do not know how to check that second actor will be got a "ok", and `mySystem` actor will be got a `AnotherMessage`

```
class MyTest(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system)
  with ImplicitSender with FunSpecLike with Matchers {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("myTest"))

  val outerResourse = new OuterResourse()
  val mySystem = system.actorOf(Props(new MySytem(outerResourse)))

  describe("Actors") {
    it("should get AnotherMessage message and ok message") {
      ???
    }
  }
}
```

Hot to check, that a `secondActor` got a "ok" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set custom `OutputStream` for `println` usnig `Console.withOut`. It could be mock and "wait" for OK message from first actor. But it is not very nice....

// edit: please read documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html 
Akka provide they owm testing "framework"

Comment: i use a `println` only for example, but it great idea use mock

Comment: More general, why you try to test whole system? Just test that actor under test do they work well. It's probably hard to write UnitTest for actor but it is not impassible

Comment: i would like to check system behaviour.